# Eclipse java editor: how to hide tab and line breaker symbols

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

Eclipse java editor:

```
Tab:  showed as >>
end of line(line breaker) : weird symbol(can not type in here)
```

Do not know how these symbols show up in editor. How to hide them?

Looked at project properties -> Java editor,  and windows -> preferences. None of the configuration are related to this.

Close the editor and restart eclipse, no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the **Window | Preferences** dialog.

Navigate to **General | Editors | Text Editors**.

Switch on or off the checkbox called **Show whitespace characters**.

[image]

Also, if you click the **configure visibility** link next to the checkbox, you can control whether each individual whitespace marker appears.

Comment: It was automatically checked. I am sure I did not check it.